# Database table design task

Tags: mysql, database-design, structure

There is a factory with 15 production lines. Each production line, every day gets its own  table and needs to fill in  efficiency measurements every hour. Table consists of columns (time periods) and  categories with sub categories which makes it around 80 rows. Here is an example:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/rhfmnv0jr/]

Could you give me any suggestions with database design ?

Requirements:

Server needs to get all table data for specific day  fast.
Server needs to retrieve a specific cell (by line number, date, time period and subcategory) fast.

Comment: i guess if we could translate the language maybe. how about one that has an hour of the day, like 10 or 15 as an int. not columnar. the display can be a list of columns, data is all on its each row in db tables

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mean it would consist 80 columns for each hour?

Comment: no. hold on. i will create an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table metric
(   -- a thing to track
    metricNum int auto_increment primary key, -- 1,2,3 etc
    metricName varchar(200) -- ie: "Splat & spild", etc
);


create table efficiency
(   -- all data for all lines for all time
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    lineNum int not null,
    theDate day not null,
    metricNum int not null,
    theHour int not null,
    theCount int not null
    -- add indexes of use
    -- add foreign key (FK) constraint(s), such as to metric
);
```

That's it. Two tables. Not each line with a new table each day.

Comment: Ok i get you now. So this would create the record only if cell contains input. but per day it might get around 600 rows. How about selecting and findig this whole data after a year or two ? Will it be ok ?

Comment: that is up to you. no row or row with a 0 or null, your call.

Comment: if/when you get a suitable answer from everyone, mark one with the Green checkmark. Let's people know you are done.